# if silence in the movie bluetooth headphones are muted - ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, audio, bluetooth

**OS:** Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
**Headphones with bluetooth:** JBL T450
**PC:** Dell Inspiron 5570

When I am watching a movie or listening a music and there is a silence my headphones are muted and just after some sound appears they are unmuted. One of the solutions is to play some sound in the background - then silence in the movie doesn't mute headphones but it's not the solution...
I checked headphones on Windows and they are not muted so I guess there is some mismatch in OS configuration.
Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the solution:

```
$ sudo vim /etc/pulse/default.pa
load-module module-udev-detect ignore_dB=1
```

More details in the [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/PulseAudio/Troubleshooting#No_sound_below_a_volume_cutoff_or_Clipping_on_a_particular_output_device).

Answer (score 2):

PulseAudio has suspended the module after detecting that no audio has been transferred. [Disable the module that does so.](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio/Troubleshooting#Bluetooth_headset_replay_problems)

> To disable loading of the `module-suspend-on-idle` module, comment out the following line in the configuration file in use (`~/.config/pulse/default.pa` or `/etc/pulse/default.pa`):
>
> ```
> ### Automatically suspend sinks/sources that become idle for too long
> #load-module module-suspend-on-idle
> ```

Comment: I am afraid it didn't solve my problem. It was only fine just after I reconfigured it like you suggested.

Comment: I have two profiles in Bluetooth settings for my Headset: High Fidelity Playback(problem with mutting) and  Headset Head Unit (NO problems with mutting but sound is terrible).